# Angular js sending auth token after request in Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, token

My auth system was behaving strangely, and I realized that `access.js`, the file that sends auth tokens in headers, gets loaded up only AFTER the client has made a request to the server. Server log:

```
Example app listening on port 3000!
couldn't find yer token, matey
gonna load the page up!
GET / 304 3.765 ms - -
couldn't find yer token, matey
GET /access.js 304 1.031 ms - -
couldn't find yer token, matey
nice token, mate
GET /main.html 304 2.192 ms - -
```

This creates the effect that every request gets a response corresponding to the token not being there. Here is `server.js`:

```
var authenticator = function(req, res, next){
    var token = req.headers['authorization'];
    if (token){
        var authenticated;
        jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function (err, decoded){
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
                authenticated = false;
                req.decoded = null;
            } else {
                req.decoded = decoded;
                authenticated = true;
                console.log("nice token, mate");
            }
        })
    }
    console.log("couldn't find yer token, matey");
    next();
    }

app.use(authenticator);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log("gonna load it up!");
    if (req.decoded == null){
        res.sendFile('/home/daniel/app/public/index.html');
    } else {
        res.send("gold!!");
    }
});
```

And here is `access.js`:

```
access.factory('AuthenticationInterceptor', ['$q', '$location', '$localStorage', function ($q, $location, $localStorage) {
return {
    'request': function (config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        if ($localStorage.token) {
            config.headers.Authorization = $localStorage.token;
        }
        return config;
    },
        'responseError': function (response) {
        if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
            $location.path('/login');
        }
        return $q.reject(response);
    }
};
}]);

access.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthenticationInterceptor');
$routeProvider

.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'main.html'
})
.when('/register', {
    templateUrl: 'register.html', controller: 'createSession'
})
.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'login.html', controller: 'createSession'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. What is a way that I can send the token without relying on the server to serve the file? Or there some routing scheme I can devise that makes the initial request take care of this logic?

Comment: Token won't exist either for users that haven't logged in. You need to do some filtering in your server side auth

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, but even for me, who has a token, the server doesn't receive one right away, making it act like I don't have one at all.

Comment: You can't authenticate main page or it's templates.